# custom sort of employees by title then last name

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting

I created a custom sort for an array of employees by title.  However, I'd like to then sort by last name (last_name).  Here is my code that sorts by title and is working, but I can't figure out how to add the :

//Build a new array to hold only the data we need, and custom sort

```
$employees = array();

  if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while($query->have_posts()){
        $query->the_post();

       
        $employees[] = array(
                        'permalink' => get_permalink(),
                        'ID' => $post->ID,
                        'thumbnail' => get_the_post_thumbnail(),
                        'name' => get_the_title(),
                        'upper_title' => ucwords( str_replace("_", " ", get_post_meta($post->ID, 'title', true)) ),
                        'meta_title' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'title', true)
                    );
       
       
    }
}


//Custom sort order, defined by customer
$order = array_flip(['managing_partner', 'partner_emeritus', 'partner', 'associate', 'senior_counsel', 'of_counsel', 'paralegal', 'transaction_analyst']);

$default = count($order);

usort($employees, function($a, $b) use($order, $default) {
    return ($order[$a['meta_title']] ?? $default) <=> ($order[$b['meta_title']] ?? $default);
});

//console_log("Here comes Employees SORTED");
//console_log($employees);

$arrlength = count($employees);

for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    //console_log($employees[$x]['meta_title']);
    $result_sorted .= '<div class="grid-item"><a href="' . $employees[$x]['permalink'] . '">' . $employees[$x]['thumbnail'] . '</a><h4>'. $employees[$x]['name'] . '</h4><p class="title">'. $employees[$x]['upper_title'] .'</p></div>';
}
```

Comment: Uou'll need to modify your sorting function within usort to include a secondary comparison. This means that if two employees have the same title, the sorting function will then compare their last names to determine their order.

Comment: As much as I like `<=>`, sometimes it is really helpful to write it out the long way first, then optimize it later.